# Product image according to selected color option on cart page Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, php, configurable-product, color-swatches

My problem is that the images of a configurable product change according to the color option on product  detail page but when I add to cart that product default image is shown on cart page while I want image according the selected color option

I have a Product with two color 'Black' and 'White'. when I click on black color the image on product detail page has been changed but when I add to cart that and check that on cart page product , product image is white which is default image.

[image]

[image]
I am using Magento 1.9. with default color swatches.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Go to

```
System > Configuration > Sales > Checkout > Shopping Cart
```

and set `Configurable Product Image` to `Product Thumbnail Itself` and hit the `Save Config` button. You may need to refresh cache as well...

After this, the image of the selected color option should be displayed in the cart.