# Magento 2 how to get product attribute options on checkout cart

Tags: magento2, attributes, attribute-options, checkout-page

How I can get the configurable products attribute options in front end checkout cart page? I have tried with the below answer but can't get any success.

[Magento 2 - How to get attribute options value of eav entity?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105167/magento-2-how-to-get-attribute-options-value-of-eav-entity)

When I have print the `echo "<pre>"; print_r($block->getOptionList()); die;`, I am getting the below array result with the label and value but not getting the color code to show as per my custom design.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [label] => Color
            [value] => Green
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [label] => Size
            [value] => S
        )

)
```

Also, I have go through the admin settings like below:

```
Stores > Configutation > Sales > Checkout > Shopping Cart > Configurable Product Image set as Product Thumbnail Itself
```

It's also not working in the magento 2.

Please see the attached screenshot what I want:
[image]

Display this color code value in the frontend like the below image:
[image]

Please suggest how I can get the color code? Thanks!!!

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64727/product-image-according-to-selected-color-option-on-cart-page-magento -> Seems not working in Magento 2.1.7

Comment: I have tried it,but it's not working in the Magento 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a module
2. Override the configurable model in

> VENDOR/MODULENAME/Model/Product/Type/Configurable.php

```
namespace VENDOR\MODULENAME\Model\Product\Type;
use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable as ConfigurableProduct;

class Configurable extends \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable
{   
    public function getUsedConfigurableProductAttributes($product)
    {       
        if (!$product->hasData($this->usedProductAttributes)) {
            $usedProductAttributes = [];
            $usedAttributes = [];
            foreach ($this->getConfigurableAttributes($product) as $attribute) {
                if ($attribute->getProductAttribute() !== null) {
                    $id = $attribute->getProductAttribute()->getId();
                    $usedProductAttributes[$id] = $attribute->getProductAttribute();
                    $usedAttributes[$id] = $attribute;
                }
            }
            $product->setData($this->_usedAttributes, $usedAttributes);
            $product->setData($this->usedProductAttributes, $usedProductAttributes);
        }
        return $product->getData($this->_usedAttributes);
    } 
}
```

3. Override the Getoptions block using plugin

   ```
   namespace VENDOR\MODULENAME\Plugin\Product;
   use Magento\Swatches\Helper\Data as SwatchData;
   use Magento\Swatches\Helper\Media;
   use VENDOR\MODULENAME\Model\Product\Type\Configurable as ConfigModel;

   class Options
   {
       protected $swatchHelper;    
       protected $swatchMediaHelper;    
       protected $configModel;

       public function __construct(
           SwatchData $swatchHelper,
           Media $swatchMediaHelper,
           ConfigModel $configModel
       )
       {
           $this->swatchHelper = $swatchHelper;
           $this->swatchMediaHelper = $swatchMediaHelper;
           $this->configModel = $configModel;        
       }

       public function aroundGetOptions(
           \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Configuration $subject,
           $proceed,
           \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Configuration\Item\ItemInterface $item
       ) {     
           $product = $item->getProduct();
           $typeId = $product->getTypeId();

           if ($typeId == \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE) {
               if($attributesOption = $product->getCustomOption('attributes')) {
                   $data = unserialize($attributesOption->getValue());  

                   $usedAttributes = $this->configModel->getUsedConfigurableProductAttributes($product);
                   $mediaUrl = $this->swatchMediaHelper->getSwatchMediaUrl();

                   foreach ($data as $attributeId => $attributeValue) {
                       if (isset($usedAttributes[$attributeId])) {
                           /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute $attribute */
                           $attribute = $usedAttributes[$attributeId]->getProductAttribute();
                           $label = $attribute->getStoreLabel();
                           $value = $attribute;
                           if ($value->getSourceModel()) {
                               $value = $value->getSource()->getOptionText($attributeValue);
                           } else {
                               $value = '';
                           }

                           $swatchesData = $this->swatchHelper->getSwatchesByOptionsId(array($attributeValue));
                           $swatchValue = $swatchesData[$attributeValue]['value'];
                           $visualSwatch = $this->swatchHelper->isVisualSwatch($attribute);
                           $swatch_value_formatted = '';

                           if($visualSwatch) {
                               if ($swatchValue[0] == '#') {
                                   $swatch_value_formatted = 'background: '.$swatchValue;
                               } elseif ($swatchValue[0] == '/') {
                                   $swatch_value_formatted = 'background: url('.$mediaUrl.$swatchValue.'); background-size: cover;';
                               }
                           }

                           $attributes[] = ['label' => $label, 'value' => $value, 'swatch_value' =>  $swatchValue, 'option_id' =>  $swatchesData[$attributeValue]['option_id'] , 'visual_swatch' => $visualSwatch , 'swatch_value_formatted' => $swatch_value_formatted  ];      
                       }
                   }
               }            
               return $attributes + $proceed($item);
           }        
           return $proceed($item);
       }
   }
   ```
4. Define the plugin and overriding model in di.xml

---

```
<preference for="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable" type="VENDOR\MODULENAME\Model\Product\Type\Configurable"/>
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Configuration">
<plugin name="My_product_options" type="\VENDOR\MODULENAME\Plugin\Product\Options" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>
```

5. In the checkout cart template you can use the following to find out the swatch is visual or not. The following values also available in the template file swatch_value, visual_swatch, swatch_value_formatted

---

```
<?php if (isset($_option['visual_swatch']) && $_option['visual_swatch']) { ?>
        <?php echo '<div class="swatch-option" style="'.$_option['swatch_value_formatted'].'"></div>'; ?>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Many Thanks lavanya, I will try it and will accept your answer. I have done it by custom query right now.

Comment: Great solution. Thanks for your help @lavanya very appreciated.

Comment: how to show dropdown value not swatch.